# Change mock object return value dynamically

Tags: java, easymock, powermock

Suppose i have the following method :

```
public void runLoop(SomeIterator it){
    while(it.hasNext()){
        //do something
    }
}
```

Now i want to pass in a `SomeIterator` Mock object that would return `Boolean.TRUE` in order to go into the loop, but I also want it to return `Boolean.FALSE` at some point (say after 10 times for example), is there a way to make this happen with PowerMock/EasyMock?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Why is your question tagged easymock if you're only interested in PowerMock?

Comment: I'm interested in both actually

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's an excerpt from the [EasyMock documentation](http://www.easymock.org/EasyMock3_1_Documentation.html):

> Changing Behavior for the Same Method Call
>
> It is also possible to specify a changing behavior for a method. The
>   methods times, andReturn, and andThrow may be chained. As an example,
>   we define voteForRemoval("Document") to
>
> - return 42 for the first three calls,
> - throw a RuntimeException for the next four calls,
> - return -42 once.

```
expect(mock.voteForRemoval("Document"))
    .andReturn((byte) 42).times(3)
    .andThrow(new RuntimeException(), 4)
    .andReturn((byte) -42);
```

Comment: Didn't think about that one - definitely easier than IAnswer if the return value can be mapped directly to call sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know powermock that well, but with easymock the way to do that is .andAnswer() instead of .andReturn on your mock.

Pseudo code:

```
it.hasNext();
expectLastCall().anyTimes().andAnswer(
    new IAnswer<Boolean>(){ compute your return value }
);
```